# Unity3D for iOS and Android: Multiplayer (Bluetooth Connection)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, unity-game-engine, p2p

i'm looking for a way to connect two devices using Bluetooth in Unity iOS and Android Basic for Multiplayer-Gaming. 
I found:

- [AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/app-developers/unity-extension) by Qualcomm - Bluetooth works apparently only with [Root](https://www.alljoyn.org/forums/developers/next-step-bluetooth-android)-Android Devices  and currently not with iOS.
- [iOS GameKit Local Multiplayer](http://u3d.as/content/prime31/i-os-game-kit-local-multiplayer/2CX) by prime31 - Only for iOS.
- [Bonjour Plugin](http://u3d.as/content/gregzo/bonjour-plugin-for-unity-i-os-zero-conf-made-easy/3oP) by Gregzo - Not Bluetooth but a other local-multiplayer solution only for iOS.
- [TNet](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=4518): Not Bluetooth, only for Android and iOS Pro

Has anyone any other solution (especially for Android)?

I would be grateful for any help. Also for other p2p-Unity-Solutions.

Comment: Connecting across platforms via Bluetooth will be really difficult. Your best bet is to use Bonjour/Zeroconf. This will mean both devices will have to be on the same WiFi network, but once one device advertises a service the other should be able to see it and join. You'll still need to write you own Unity plugin for Android though. http://android.noisepages.com/2010/02/yes-android-can-do-zeroconfbonjour-jmdns/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For [Ships N' Battles](http://skahal.com/ships-n-battles) (a cross platform multiplayer game Unity authored) we have built several ways to perform a multiplayer game:

**via Bluetooth (using Prime31 plugin)**

- iOS

*I've never seen a game with multiplayer between iOS and Android using Bluetooth.*

**via LAN (using [Unity RPC](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/net-RPCDetails.html))**

- iOS
- Android
- Mac
- Web (Kongregate)

*The players can start combats in a Local Area Network with any of above devices: iOS vs iOS, iOS vs Android, Android vs Mac, and so on.*

**via Game Center (using Prime31 plugin)**

- iOS

*Uses the Game Center multiplayer to match combats.*

**via Global Server (an in-house solution)**

- iOS
- Android
- Mac
- Web (Kongregate)

*The players can start combats around the world with any of above devices: iOS vs iOS, iOS vs Android, Android vs Mac, and so on.*

For this solution we have built a online server, but you can use something like [Photon](http://www.exitgames.com/Photon/Unity).

Answer (score 2):

For Android, you can use plugin I've released recently: [Android Bluetooth Multiplayer](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/188667-Android-Bluetooth-Multiplayer-Released)

For iOS, I've made a plugin as well: [Local Multiplayer for iOS/tvOS/macOS](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/188667-Android-Bluetooth-Multiplayer-Released)

Both are designed to be compatible with Unity built-in multiplayer, so you can use any of existing tutorials about Unity built-in networking or reuse your existing networking code with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

Unity Announcing [**UNET**](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/12/announcing-unet-new-unity-multiplayer-technology/) (UDP based Multiplayer)

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unet-sample-projects.331978/

Comment: UDP is restricted on Mobile.